# How to calculate the current consumed by a brushless motor on a quadcopter

Tags: motor, quadcopter, brushless-motor, electronics, power

I want to create a virtual quadcopter model, but I am struggling to come up with a satisfying model for the brushless motors & props.

Let's take an example, based on the great [eCalc tool](http://www.ecalc.ch/xcoptercalc.php?ecalc&lang=en):

[image: eCalc]

Let's say I want to know how much current is consumed by the motor in a hovering state. I know the mass of the quad (1500g), so I can easily compute the thrust produced by each motor:

```
Thrust = 1.5 * 9.81 / 4 = 3.68 N per motor
```

[Thrust is produced by moving a mass of air](http://www.wired.com/2014/05/modeling-the-thrust-from-a-quadcopter/) at an average speed of `V`:

```
Thrust = 0.5 * rho * A * V²
```

Where `rho` (air density) is 1.225kg/m3 and `A` (propeller disk area) is `PI * Radius² = 0.073m²` (12" props). So I can compute `V`:

```
V = sqrt(Thrust / 0.5 / rho / A) = 9.07 m/s
```

All right, now I can calculate the *aerodynamic* power created by the propeller:

```
P = Thrust * V = 3.68 * 9.07 = 33.4 W
```

All right, now I can calculate the *mechanical* power actually produced by the motor. I use the `PConst` efficiency term from eCalc:

```
Pmec = Paero * PConst = 33.4 * 1.18 = 39.4W
```

Here, eCalc predicts **37.2W**. It's not too far from my number, I imagine they use more sophisticated hypotheses... Fair enough.

From [this post](http://www.rcgroups.com/forums/showthread.php?t=587549), I know that this power is also equal to:

```
Pmec = (Vin - Rm * Iin) * (Iin - Io)
```

Where I know `Rm` (0.08 Ohms) and `Io` (0.9 A). So, finally, my question: How do you calculate `Vin` and `Iin` from here? Of course, if I knew the rotation speed of the engine I could get `Vin` from:

```
n = Kv * Vin
```

Where `Kv = 680 rpm/V`. But unfortunately I don't know the rotation speed...

(Note that Vin is assumed to be averaged from the [pulse-width-modulated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-width_modulation) output produced by the ESC)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

n = Kv * Vin only when there is no load on the motor. When there is a load on the motor, like from a propeller, you will need to be a bit more clever.

For a DC motor (which BLDC motors approximate by varying the Vin):

Torque = Kt * Vin / R - Ke * Kt * n / R

(Derivation example here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/90933/torque-relationship-to-speed-in-a-dc-motor)

Back the the propeller:

Paero = Thrust * Vp = torque * n

Vp = 0.5 * (Ve + Vac)

Since velocity of the aircraft at hover is 0, Vp becomes 0.5 * Ve

You actually used the Vp = 0.5 * (Ve + Vac) equation implicitly when you defined thrust. Those equations come from momentum theory. (Good read here: https://web.mit.edu/16.unified/www/FALL/thermodynamics/notes/node86.html)

From there you can solve for Vin and then Iin. Do note, this is the current and voltage of the motor. The ESc will be pulling from a higher voltage and lower current (but same power ignoring ESC losses)

Answer (score 1):

The missing piece was the expression of the pitch speed, which relates the parameter `V` with the rotation speed `n` and the `pitch` of the propeller:

```
V = n x pitch x (0.0254 / 60)
```

(The coefficient passes from in/min to m/s)

Knowing `V` and `pitch`, I can evaluate `n`, then `(Vin - Rm * Iin)`, and finally `Iin` (since I know everything else).

By the way, I also recommend [this link](http://www.electricrcaircraftguy.com/2014/04/propeller-static-dynamic-thrust-equation-background.html), which contains theoretical propeller formulas, corrected empirically.